# Validate method is not being invoked from controller class

Tags: java, spring

Validate method is not being invoked from controller class, but its directly executing return statement. Custom validation is not executing.

**Controller Class:**

```
package com.cluster;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class MyController {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public ModelAndView index() {

  User user = new User();
    return new ModelAndView("index","user",user);
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/display")
  public String  display(Model model, @ModelAttribute("user")User 
      user,BindingResult result) {

    System.out.println("intocontroller");
    UserValidator userValidator = new UserValidator();
    userValidator.validate(user, result);
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
      System.out.println("into error loop");
      return "index";
    }
    return "redirect:/check";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/check")
  public ModelAndView check() {
    return new ModelAndView("success");
  }
}
```

**Validator Class:**

```
package com.cluster;

import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

public class UserValidator implements Validator{

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class clazz){

    return User.class.equals(clazz);
  }

  @Override // getting object and bindingresult reference 
  public void validate(Object target,Errors errors) {

    User user =(User)target;
    if(user.getFname()==null){
      errors.rejectValue("fname","Name shouldnt be null");
    }
    //validating the field
    if(user.getLname()==null){      
      errors.rejectValue("lname","Name shouldnt be null");
    }
  }
}
```

**POJO class:**

```
package com.cluster;

public class User {

  private String fname;
  private String lname;

  public String getFname() {
    return fname;
  }
  public void setFname(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
  }
  public String getLname() {
    return lname;
  }
  public void setLname(String lname) {
    this.lname = lname;
  }
}
```

Its entering the controller method but object of user validation class is not executing.

And please explain to me how to post questions on Stack Overflow, it's telling me to format the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve contain all the crucial information you'll need to learn how to craft great questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the entity listeners

[documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html)

[Example](http://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa)